# How to associate Javascript functions with buttons?

Tags: javascript, function, events, button

[javascript](http://pastebin.com/auVyebzN)

[html](http://pastebin.com/V8ynPn6X)

I feel as though I am doing this correctly, but for whatever reason, it isn't working. I've made sure that the link to my Javascript file is present and in correct syntax.

```
 <script src="speedreader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in the header.

I have

```
<button id="start" onclick="start();" type="button">Start</button>
```

This is obstrusive Javascript, but it won't work with

```
    var startButton = document.getElementByID("start");
    startButton.onclick = start;
```

so I've had no choice but to resort to it.

My function that I'm attempting to associate with this button is the most basic thing. Just to test to see if a Javascript function will work at all.

```
function start() {
        alert("this is working");
    }
```

Comment: You could make sure of correct spelling of the method names too ; ). `getElementByID !== getElementById`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize!

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought you were talking about my function start().

Comment: I misread your comment, sorry.

Comment: you also use **;** in function call

Answer (score 2):

If you're loading your script in the header and are trying to `getElementById` there, **the element won't yet be parsed/created**.

Put the `<script>` tag which loads your script at the end of the page, or at least listen for the DOM to be ready before you try to bind elements.

Comment: Is there some other problem that may be the issue? Even when I adjust the spelling of getElementById, it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Any errors? Have you looked at your Javascript console?

Comment: Do you mean error messages? I haven't encountered any.

Comment: And you *have* looked at your Javascript console?

Comment: The only thing that happens is that the button itself is highlighted, and remains highlighted.

Comment: You. Have. Looked. At. Your. Javascript. Console. Yes. Or. No?

Comment: I just checked. There was an unexpected parenthesis in my Javascript file which I removed. No other messages.

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: Please look at this, I've made a little plunkr sample based on the answers by @deceze and by Teemu' comment and it actually works! http://plnkr.co/edit/kI7GpgJvrkA1gCIlcvuv?p=preview

Comment: Maybe this is something wrong with my computer? I can't seem to see how to replicate that result for myself in my program. It works if I just copy-paste that, but the function in the code doesn't work

Comment: @user Your computer is probably fine. It's impossible to diagnose this specifically for you without having all the possible details.

Comment: @user Only the bare minimum necessary that reproduces this problem please. Don't post pages and pages of code.

Comment: Okay. please check my edit. I'll take out anything that I'm sure doesn't contribute to the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function myFunction() {
alert("HELLO WORLD");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Turned on your javascipt in browser[image]

Comment: Oddly enough, that still doesn't seem to do anything. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: its simple on click event that assure javascript is working..Have u still faced problems??

Comment: As in, am I still facing the same issue? Yes.

Comment: No alert message popped up.

Comment: its working fine i think your browser has disabled javascript

Comment: @user3450277 Check it your settings

Comment: my browser does have javascript enabled so that doesn't seem to be the issue

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to assign event handler for onclick in code you should write:

```
var startButton = document.getElementById("start");
if (startButton)
  startButton.click = start;
```